# How to solve the pipe efficiency problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am working on my math problems and there is a problem I have been trying to solve but I can't be able to solve so far.  The question is the following:

A pipe that contributes 20.6% of the total volume of the water of a tank only costs 14% of the total among of money you can spend on the rent of pipes, this is the ideal case where you get an optimum 100% efficiency (volume of water using a pipe and the cost of renting a pipe). Now, what would be the efficiency if the same pipe only contributed 15.7% of the total volume and you pay 23.1% for its use? You can pay less and have a larger volume and that would be an efficiency larger than 100% and it is fine. You can also pay more and have more volume but the ideal would be that the maximum cost is 15.7%. I tried to solve this problem by using a set of equations but I think I am missing some variables: 20.6A+15.7B=100 and 10.3A+ 8.85B=50 Any suggestions?

Comment: For the 20.6% volume, 14% of cost scenario, what is the efficiency?

Comment: That represents the case with 100%  volume-cost-efficiency